# Need input on missing soap information derived from a WSDL file

Tags: postman, wsdl, soapui, soap-client, postman-collection-runner

I am trying to import a WSDL file into Postman for development. It has been a very long time since I have worked with SOAP files. I seem to remember that I could get all the documentation I needed for the app from within the WSDL file.  I have the file but every time I import it gives me the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <error>The element or type could not be found executeSearchBulk</error>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: When you import a WSDL in Postman, you'll get a list of available SOAP operations as requests. For each request, you'll need to fill in the appropriate parameters and make the call. When do you get that error? By the looks of it you made a call to the SOAP service and you got back an error. Maybe you could first play with this WSDL first: http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl

Comment: Also, as a refresher on WSDL/SOAP, I recommend https://d-petre-bogdan.medium.com/the-wsdl-is-not-the-soap-web-service-97f307c4a90b